# Download c++ in existing visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I downloaded the visual studio 2017 with c# and xamarin when it gave me a lot of choices at installation time, now I want to install c++ also in existing vs2017. How can I do that? I don't want to install the whole visual studio again.

Answer (score 8):

1.Go to Control panel

2.In the Add or Remove Programs dialog box, select the product you want to repair and then click `Change/Remove`

3.In the Setup wizard, click Next

4.Click Repair

5.Then Modify it by selecting `C++` to add it.

**Note : This work in Window OS only**

Answer (score 7):

Alternative answer (less searching needed) : Visual Studio 2017 also adds the " Visual Studio Installer"  directly to the Windows Start Menu (this is the same executable used by @John Joe's answer).